# Blog Engine data storage better options

Tags: xml, database, blogengine.net

I want to use blog engine .net source to my blog. Here they provide XML and database provider to store data. By default its used xml provider. I want to which one will give the better performance XML or DB?

I have used more than 200 posts in my blog, hence we are handling large amount of data, what we use XML provider or DB provider?

Please provide any article that says the providers performance.

Regards,
Karthik.

Answer (score 2):

Working with BlogEngine.Net since 2010, and working with 100's of websites running BlogEngine.Net.

The big heated discussion about XML vs Database

Has always been in debate over which one is better than the other.

The decision on which one to use really comes down to the specific user preference.

Performance wise as long you have enough RAM (App_Pool) memory on your server to store all of your posts xml or database will not matter.

Looking behind the scenes on how BlogEngine.Net works it really treats both methods the same.

XML or Database BlogEngine.Net will load up all of the posts and settings into your Application Pool.

It is kept there until the application pool is reset which is normally every 30 mins of inactivity.

Then the next visitor that vists for the "1st Re-load" will experience a slightly slower loading that a normal in-memory load.

Because BE is reloading from XML or Database back into your application pool.

Now comes the area where a Database would provide better performance when compared with xml storage.

1. Have over 200 posts and you only have 200 MB or less of Application Pool Memory
2. Multiple servers with load balancers
3. You have over 200 users
4. You need to have custom fields for post or page

The main and real issue is not your data storage source but your physical server resources that you have, which includes the Application Pool (RAM).

As long you have enough Memory to store all of your posts and settings at once either method is basically the same.